# Can the South (for Django) insert rows of data into database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south, insertion

I want to create a table, and then a list of data that should be inserted into that table. Does South have the capability to do such a thing? If so, do you have any reference as to show me how this can be done?

I want to be able to do this because at this point, it seems like the only way to have the 'exact' same data is to manually insert them into the database ourselves.

I want some 'nice' automated way of inserting rows in a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use [fixtures](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html#initial-data).

1. Create a fixtures directory in your app's folder.
2. Create a dictionary file in that folder, intial_data.json (or XML/YAML)
3. Populate the file with the data you'd want to insert. [Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)
4. Run `manage.py loaddata <fixturename>`, where `<fixturename>` is the name of the fixture file you've created.

South handles this pretty much the same way, but it seems like Django's core approach is more documented.

Comment: You can also use direct SQL statements.

Comment: Or you can create a data migration. python manage.py datamigration app_label migration_name

Comment: I think fixture are more what I want.
Can you tell me, though, why it has to be in the format of "myapp.table_name" instaed of just "table_name"?

Comment: @Apothem I believe it's because Django needs to find specific SQL files to hook in to. So it knows then to look in the `myapp` folder for the necessary SQL file associated with the model/table. I could be wrong though.

Comment: JSON, XML, CSV these are the formats that data usually comes in, not SQL. Data migrations need to accept this and provide an easy solution for working with these

Answer (score 7):

You can! It's called a ["data migration"](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html).

There are plenty of times you might want to use one: the link above gives a good example, another is the ["data migration for every Django project"](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html):

```
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.conf import settings

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        Site = orm['sites.Site']
        site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)
        site.domain = settings.DOMAIN_NAME
        site.name = settings.SITE_NAME
        site.save()
```

(this picks up the domain and site name from `settings.py`, for use with the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/))

Comment: In some cases, a South data migration is better than a fixture as a way to set initial data.  Fixtures either need to be manually executed (with loaddata) or, if named initial_data.json, get automatically inserted into your DB every time you run syncdb.  In my experience syncdb gets run quite often, but if you create a data migration, it should only get run once per database, automatically when you run manage.py migrate.

Comment: Yeah, who do you dump a large amount of set data? Whats the format, SQL? That is ugly as you have to somehow get the data into the DB in the first place. Suppose i have a spreadsheet...?

Comment: @CpILL you can use fixtures, a database dump or a `manage.py` command that imports a spreadsheet directly. This solution with South is just for small inserts that should live in the codebase.