# how to populate database fields when model changes in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-south

I have a django app that is evolving.  The model often changes and I use Django South to apply schema migrations.

Sometimes my changes involve populating new values that are added based on sql logic.

For example, added a new boolean flag for currently paying users.  I have added the field, applied the migration but now I want to populate the field based on the data from other table to show who is paying.

I know I can do this with a simple sql statement, but my environment is automated and uses CI.  I want to push changes and have the flag populated automatically.

How can I accomplish this? With South? With Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thing called [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations), this is a perfect use case for it:

> Data migrations are used to change the data stored in your database to
>   match a new schema, or feature.

```
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.conf import settings

class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        # update your user's boolean flag here
```

See an example of a data migration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873646/771848).

Or, alternatively, you can open your schema migration `.py` file and populate your field in `forwards()` method, like this:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'User.paying'
        db.add_column(u'user', 'paying',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        # update your user's boolean flag here

    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'User.paying'
        db.delete_column(u'user', 'paying')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code in migration script created by *south*.

If you have updated a model and done `schemamigration` with south, it will create a script to apply that migration. It will be in `appname/migration/00N_some_name.py`.

You can add your code in `forwards()` method in that script at the end after schema alteration is done.